# replace a string from List elements

Tags: scala, list

I have a list in scala

```
List("Date=2018-02-19","Date=2018-02-25","Date=2018-03-03")
```

I need to remove the "Date=" from each elements in the list and final result should be

```
List("2018-02-19","2018-02-25","2018-03-03")
```

Can anyone please suggest me any efficient method to implement this ??

Comment: `List("Date=2018-02-19","Date=2018-02-25","Date=2018-03-03").map(x => x.replaceAll("Date=",""))`

Comment: thanks, actually the code is like val y = List("Date=2018-02-19","Date=2018-02-25","Date=2018-03-03")
So, is it right y.map(x => x.replaceAll("Date=",""))
??

Comment: x is just a variable name

Comment: ok,So, is this right y.map(x => x.replaceAll("Date=","")) ??

Comment: if `y` is list of dates, then yes

Answer (score 5):

```scala
val y = List("Date=2018-02-19","Date=2018-02-25","Date=2018-03-03")
val dates = y.map(_.drop(5)) // drops the first 5 characters ("Date=") of each string
dates.foreach(println)
```

```
2018-02-19
2018-02-25
2018-03-03
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call the `map` function on the list. Map applies a function to each element in a collection, the list in this case. In your case you will want to call `replaceAll` and replace `Date=` with an empty string.

```
val list = List("Date=2018-02-19","Date=2018-02-25","Date=2018-03-03")
val newList = list.map(element => elemet.replaceAll("Date=", ""))
```

Comment: @JonathanMyers lol, your answer is probably more idiomatic scala, it's been awhile since I've coded in scala